# Problem with nested resources with Kaminari pagination gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pagination, kaminari

Can't seem to get Kaminari to work properly with nested resources. Here is a description of my problem. Wondering if anybody was able to tackle this issue.

My routes look like:

```
resources :artists do
  resources :paintings
end
```

In my view, I have:

```
<%= paginate @paintings, :params => { :controller => 'paintings', :action => 'index' } %>
```

The initial / base url looks like this:

```
http://localhost/artists/foobar/paintings
```

But clicking on a kaminari paginate link, renders the url like this:

```
http://localhost/paintings?artist_id=foobar&page=2
```

It's supposed to be:

```
http://localhost/artists/foobar/paintings?page=2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ooops. Just realised, apparently a route was being prioritized....

Seems to work now...

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this same problem myself - in case anyone else ends up on this page this is how I solved it:

In routes.rb you need to move your "outer" route to below your nested. So if you had:

```
resources :questions
resources :subject_areas do
  resources :questions
end
```

you need to change it to:

```
resources :subject_areas do
  resources :questions
end
resources :questions
```

This made the pagination links start working as expected above.