# Kaminari pagination with fields_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, kaminari

I have a form for a company model:

```
<%= form_for(@company) do |f| %>
```

I also have a fields_for section to edit the imports relation:

```
<%= f.fields_for(:imports) do |builder| %>
```

Company has_many :imports
and
Import belongs_to :company

I want to use Kaminari for pagination, but the problem is, Kaminari needs a page object returned from the controller like such:

```
@imports = Import.where(:company_id => current_user.company.id).page(params[:page]).per(50)
```

This allows me to use the paginate method from Kaminari:

```
<%= paginate @imports %>
```

That works, and displays the page links on my form, however, they are obviously not linked to my fields_for block.

My question is, how can I accomplish pagination with a fields_for block?
I need to allow the user to edit a list of Import models, and there will probably be too many to fit on one page which is why I'm trying to paginate. Basically I'm trying to create a spreadsheet like experience for the user.

I don't need to use Kaminari, but I'm on Rails 3.1 and it seemed to be the popular choice.

Thanks for any help on this.

Comment: have you considered will_paginate? Another popular option.  Not sure if it would address your issue thus comment

Comment: I just watched Ryan Bates rails cast http://railscasts.com/episodes/254-pagination-with-kaminari and he said will_paginate seems to be unsupported... I could use the pre release version for rails 3 as he suggests.

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5457580/problem-with-nested-resources-with-kaminari-pagination-gem

Comment: I appreciate the reference, but it looks like that issue was related to routing, my issue is not routing, its a matter of making paging work in conjunction with a fields_for block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use 'fields_for` with a collection of objects as well.

So you can do

```
<%= f.fields_for(:imports, @imports) do |builder| %>
```

If that answers your question then you're done! However if you want it to be a 'spreadsheet' like ordeal then maybe not so much.

The problem being that if you do that each time you go to a new page you will lose all your edited `imports`.

It may be simpler to do this:

- Build all the `fields_for` and hide them.
- Then build your own AJAX 'pagination'.

That way when the submit the changes it will pass all the `imports` and their changes instead of just the current page.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer because using fields_for with a collection definitely solves my pagination problem.  You brought up a great point about loosing edits while switching pages though, thanks for answer.